# HTTP response code on button click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, httpwebrequest

Trying to build a C# application (my first, so apologies if this is a stupid question)I have a button on the `form` , that when clicked will check `HTTP connectivity` to a `webserver`.

There are no errors in the compile but its always returning "`connection error`"

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com");
        httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;


        HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();

        if (httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("200 OK");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection error!");
        }

        // Close the response.
        httpRes.Close();

    }
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check *what* status code is returned. That might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes a website just Responses "Found" and not "OK"

```
if (httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found || httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
```

[EDIT]
Threre are some other Errors like "Moved Permanently"  so just decide what is an Error and what not

Answer (score 1):

since the code you provided didn't cover all status codes i would suggest you add this into the else block:

```
MessageBox.Show(httpRes.StatusCode.ToString());
```

with this you should get the status code and the codes for html responses is here:
[W3 HTML Response codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)